# Java: Referencing a file after being packaged (jar), getResourceAsStream?

Tags: java, maven, file, jar, stream

I'm trying to implement a button into my project which, when clicked, automatically loads a specific file. Currently there are buttons for users selecting a file from their hard disk.

So, I downloaded the specific file and inserted it into the project. When using File f = new File("demofile") or something like this 
getClass().getResource("/resources/file.txt").getFile(); the code WORKS locally.

However, when the project is packaged, a FileNotFoundException is thrown.

After much research online, there are suggestions to use something like:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/file.txt");
```

However, for this project, I need the file to be referenced as a file object so that it can be passed as an argument to other functions, such as:

```
in = new TextFileFeaturedSequenceReader(TextFileFeaturedSequenceReader.FASTA_FORMAT, file, DiffEditFeaturedSequence.class);
```

Any ideas on how I can solve this, or read a stream into a file object?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't. Time to redesign your program so it doesn't use `File`. If there's a `TextFileFeaturedSequenceReader`, there's probably another class that takes a different kind of input (like `InputStream`).

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely must pass a File, copy your resource to a [temporary file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-):

```
Path path = Files.createTempFile(null, null);
try (InputStream stream =
        getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/file.txt")) {

    Files.copy(stream, path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}

in = new TextFileFeaturedSequenceReader(
    TextFileFeaturedSequenceReader.FASTA_FORMAT,
    path.toFile(),
    DiffEditFeaturedSequence.class);

// Use the TextFileFeaturedSequenceReader as needed

// ...

Files.delete(path);
```